# Change JUnit version in Intellij IDEA 2016.3?

Tags: intellij-idea, junit, dependencies, junit4, junit5

After adding JUnit5 to my dependencies (via `alt+enter` and selecting the option to do so) so I can run tests by right-clicking, the test runner fails to detect any of my tests. After consulting with some colleagues it seems that they require JUnit4. However, I've looked everywhere and I can't find a way to change the JUnit dependency version from JUnit5 to Junit4.

Is there a standard way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm one of the maintainers of JUnit 5. The new JUnit platform that is being introduced with JUnit 5 can run JUnit 4 tests and IDEA should be able to handle this. What versions of JUnit 4 and 5 are you using? Please raise an issue in [IntelliJ's bug tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA) or for [JUnit 5 on GitHub](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues).